# constantly watching the battery?

Tags: android, battery

I dont know if this can be done but right now i have a service that has an alarm manager which refreshed the battery every 5 mins to check the battery % and alert of the battery gets below a certain %. Is there a better way to watch the battery that does not require an alarm manager and refreshes when the battery changes because it seems better than refreshing after a certain amount of time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tyczj,

I would create a `BroadcastReceiver` to receive the following Broadcast: [`ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED).  This way you aren't constantly polling the battery unnecessarily.

Additional:

It would be registered like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".BatteryReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: I tried using a broadcast receiver before and it never was broadcasted, it would be registered by doing <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED"/> right?

Comment: tried that and it still does not work, reading through the docs for that i found this, "You can not receive this through components declared in manifests, only by explicitly registering for it with Context.registerReceiver(). See ACTION_BATTERY_LOW, ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY, ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED, and ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED for distinct battery-related broadcasts that are sent and can be received through manifest receivers." 

does that mean i have to register it somewhere else before it will be fired?

Comment: Yes, in this particular case you must programatically register it using `registerReceiver()` in `onResume()` of your `Activity` and unregister it using `unregisteReceiver()` in `onPause()`.

Comment: that would mean that i would have to have the program running correct? i want to monitor the battery in the background though

Comment: It seems by disabling the ability to register the receiver in your `AndroidManifest` they intentionally don't want you catching the broadcast without your program active.  You may need to use a `Service` to accomplish constant monitoring. :[

Answer (score 2):

You can listen to the systems broadcast intents:

[ACTION_BATTER_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)

[ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED)

[ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED)